# Metro App with 2D Graphics in C#

Tags: c#, 2d, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have done some looking and I can't figure out a good way to write a 2D tile/sprite based game in C# for Win8. According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452780.aspx) documentation:

> You can use managed code languages like C# and Visual Basic to develop 2D (and lightweight 3D) games.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to do this. The reason I would like to use C# is because I already have a lot of code written for Windows Phone that I would like to reuse.

Can anyone point me to how I would write a fairly efficient 2D tile/sprite MetroUI game for Win8? The only thing I can find uses C++ and DirectX.

[EDIT]

To clarify I do not care too much what I use (WinRT, DirectX...) so long as I can submit to the app store, and write my code in C#.

Comment: I guess with metro-ui you mean WinRT? Have a look at this document http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/4/1E455D53-C382-4A39-BA73-55413F183333/Windows_Developer_Preview-Windows8_guide.pdf it explains what options you have to write games. To make it short, you can use Direct2D, Direct3D and some helper stuff from XNA will also be available. But if you just want to make a game, that runs on win8 without WinRT this will also be possible, but might not work on tablets or the propably upcoming windows phone 8. Also WinRT is compatible to c#,so directx support will probably expand to c# aswell

Comment: This still wasn't much help. It was very generic.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Rgarding your edit and comment. What did you expect? You want to be able to submit to the appstore, afaik you must use WinRT. Whats possible with WinRT is written in this document. And on top of all that, win8 and winrt is not final. The whole API and alot of components are not finished and maybe will completely change. So for now you can use what the developer preview of winrt offers you, which to be fair is not much for game development needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with the DirectX API, you can use SharpDX available via [http://sharpdx.org](http://www.sharpdx.org). It is basically exposing DirectX APIs into C#. From my understanding, if you are going to upload apps to the store, the SharpDX should be fine and pass compliance, but I would look into it further before going too deep.

Also, as of this time, not all of the features are available (like Direct2d not fully certified for Win8 Metro).

Comment: From what i understand he wants to use WinRT. And i don't think slimdx is WinRT ready nor necessary. Because in WinRT directx will be available again.

Answer (score 0):

If your game uses simple graphics, you can use [Drawing Library for Modern UI](http://www.moderncomponents.com/products/DrawingLibrary/), it exposes a GDI+ like interface to be used in XAML/C#/VB.NET Windows 8 Modern UI applications, it works by drawing to a XAML Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something quick and easy check out the "Physics Helper XAML" project;

http://physicshelperxaml.codeplex.com/

It's based on the farseer engine, and comes with sample apps. There are a few games already released using it.

http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/223/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:
 [XAML images sample]  (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9/sourcecode?fileId=102748&pathId=677969581)

The page and samples give some code for NineGrid and WriteableBitmap Image manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [Win2D](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm) (open source, released by Microsoft for metro/WinRT apps) which provides hardware-accelerated 2D graphics rendering.